# Keras Conv2DTranspose layers in Convolutional GAN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to train a Convolutional GAN in Keras with Tensorflow backend for generating faces. Having read several examples there seem to be two ways to build the generator, you can either use the Conv2DTranspose layer with strides to upsample, like so:

```
def build_generator(seed_size, channels):
    inputs_rand = Input(shape=(seed_size,))
    inputs_feat = Input(shape=(NUM_FEATS,))
    inputs = Concatenate()([inputs_rand, inputs_feat])

    dense1 = Dense(4*4*64, activation='relu')(inputs)
    reshape1 = Reshape((4,4,64))(dense1)

    conv_trans1 = Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2*GENERATE_RES, padding='same')(reshape1)
    batch_norm1 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(conv_trans1)
    leaky_relu1 = ReLU()(batch_norm1)

    conv_trans2 = Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same')(leaky_relu1)
    batch_norm2 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(conv_trans2)
    leaky_relu2 = ReLU()(batch_norm2)

    conv_trans3 = Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same')(leaky_relu2)
    batch_norm3 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(conv_trans3)
    leaky_relu3 = ReLU()(batch_norm3)

    output = Conv2DTranspose(channels, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh')(leaky_relu3)

    generator = Model(inputs=[inputs_rand, inputs_feat], outputs=[output, inputs_feat])
    return generator
```

or use the Upsample2D layer along with Conv2D layers, like so:

```
def build_generator(seed_size, channels):
    inputs_rand = Input(shape=(seed_size,))
    inputs_feat = Input(shape=(NUM_FEATS,))
    inputs = Concatenate()([inputs_rand, inputs_feat])

    dense1 = Dense(4*4*64, activation='relu')(inputs)
    reshape1 = Reshape((4,4,64))(dense1)

    upsamp1 = UpSampling2D(2*GENERATE_RES)(reshape1)
    conv_trans1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, padding='same')(upsamp1)
    batch_norm1 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(conv_trans1)
    leaky_relu1 = ReLU()(batch_norm1)

    upsamp2 = UpSampling2D()(leaky_relu1)
    conv_trans2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, padding='same')(upsamp2)
    batch_norm2 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(conv_trans2)
    leaky_relu2 = ReLU()(batch_norm2)

    upsamp3 = UpSampling2D()(leaky_relu2)
    conv_trans3 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, padding='same')(upsamp3)
    batch_norm3 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(conv_trans3)
    leaky_relu3 = ReLU()(batch_norm3)

    output = Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='tanh')(leaky_relu3)

    generator = Model(inputs=[inputs_rand, inputs_feat], outputs=[output, inputs_feat])
    return generator
```

I have read in a few places that Conv2DTranspose is preferable, however I can't seem to get it working. It just produces a repeating noise pattern according to the strides, and then no matter how long I leave it to train, it stays the same. Meanwhile the other method seems to work well enough, but I would like to get both methods working (just to satisfy my own curiosity). I think I must be doing something wrong, but my code looks pretty much the same as other examples I've found and I can't find anyone else having this sort of problem.

I have tried a few tweaks to the model, for example adding dropout and removing the batch normalisation just in case there was a simple fix, but nothing seems to work. I haven't included the rest of my code to keep things tidy, if it would help, though, I can add the rest.

[This is the noise obtained when using the Conv2DTranspose layers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gmcf.png)

[Meanwhile the Upsampling with Conv2D layers produce these, for example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlCLg.png)

Any comments and suggestions on how to improve my results would be welcomed too.

Comment: Where did you read that transposed conv is preferable? There is a nice discussion [here](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/) which explains the problems transposed convolutions have. One takeaway is that you might want to try using filter sizes that are multiples of the stride (e.g. 4 instead of 5). Also, perhaps check the [DCGAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06434.pdf) architecture. I'm afraid it's difficult to give concrete advice that is appropriate as an answer on this site.

Comment: I was using this github post https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks as guidance, and it suggests transposed conv for upsampling (I've just spotted that it says pixel shuffle as well, so maybe that's what I was missing? Not sure what it is though). Since you have pointed me towards these resources it seems that it may be best to just stick with upsampling. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Interesting. Note that the DCGAN paper I linked *does* use transposed conv as well. There is also TF code [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan). No harm done in giving it a try, I suppose.